# Send PHP Mail in intervals

Tags: email, php

I'm working on a simple text messaging service for my high school's student council and my hosting service only allows 19 PHP mail messages to be sent per minute, so is there a way I can set an interval to only send 15 emails, wait a minute, send another 15, wait, and do so until all the mail is sent? Below is some of my code, all you'll probably need to see is the "foreach" section.

```
$subject =     ""; 
$message =     "Hey, $first! $messageget";

$header =     'From: Student Council<email@email.net>' . "\r\n" .
               'Reply-To: email@email.net' . "\r\n" . 
              'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion(); 


foreach($to as $value) { 

    $result = mail($value, $subject, $message, $header); 



}
```

Comment: Is the limit the same for delivering directly to SMTP?

Comment: For SMTP it's 9 emails/minute. If that's what you're asking?

Comment: I'm not familiar with cronjobs, but for more information the messages will be different each time, the student council president will log onto my website and type a message then send it.

Comment: Can you add the recipients as BCC, then you would be able to send to many more recipients in the same batch? It has some backdraws however (more likely to get caught by spam-filters etc) but could be used in this case maybe?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sending 15 Mails in 60 seconds is equivalent to sending one mail every 4 seconds.

So if you have a loop that would send all mails one after another, you decelerate by doing a `sleep(4)` after every mail is sent.

```
foreach($to as $value) { 
    $result = mail($value, $subject, $message, $header); 
    sleep(4);
}
```

This is way easier than calculating when to send the next batch of 15 mails and then wait another 60 seconds. :)

Additionally, it evens out the usage of CPU and network ressources and does not peak after 60 seconds.

Comment: Brilliant! No clue why I didn't think of that after people suggesting using sleep(); Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

You can use cron jobs for this situation.
 http://www.google.com.tr/?q=cron+job+sending+email+php&oq=php+cron+job+sending
https://serverfault.com/questions/421485/cron-job-sending-bulk-emails-at-a-time

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach($to as $i=>$value) { 
    if($i%15==1) sleep(60);
    $result = mail($value, $subject, $message, $header);
}
```

The Count can be done with Modulus $i%15 (run every 15th time) and then pause with sleep(60);

(This above answer assumes your array_keys are numeric and in order, you could also use:)

```
$i=0;
foreach($to as $value) { 
    if($i%15==1) sleep(60);
    $result = mail($value, $subject, $message, $header);
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! This answered my question exactly, but Sven suggested a much simpler way. Voted you up though!

Answer (score 1):

You just use the function:

```
 sleep(60);
```

Put it in your loop.

EDIT:

for email counts, just add up the sent emails in the loop:

```
$i=0;  // about the foreach loop
```

and inside the loop call

```
if($i<15){ $i++; continue; }
else{ $i=0; }

sleep(60);
```

Hope that clears it up.

EDIT2:   and if that doesn't, here:

```
$subject =     ""; 
$message =     "Hey, $first! $messageget";

$header =     'From: Student Council<email@email.net>' . "\r\n" .
               'Reply-To: email@email.net' . "\r\n" . 
              'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion(); 

$i=0;
foreach($to as $value) { 

    $result = mail($value, $subject, $message, $header); 

    if($i<15){ $i++; continue; }

  sleep(60);
}
```

Comment: is that in seconds? Not in milliseconds?

Comment: Thanks for the feed back! Wouldn't I need to somehow have a count though? How would I go about doing that?

Comment: It does count. It runs the first foreach, then pauses for 60 seconds per that example, and then continues until then next.  If you need a counter, define a variable outside the loop  $i=0;   and inside the loop call $i++  to increment on each iteration.

Comment: Problem is: How to send 15 mails every 60 seconds... This is not solved in your answer.

Comment: I just put it in the comment above yours.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Sven nailed it though

Comment: yeah, I told you the function to use first.  It was basic math.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `sleep()` function :

```
 sleep(60); // wait during 60 seconds
```